# Json eval function in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
var jsonCallbackCode1 = eval("employees = { 'accounting' : [ { 'firstName' : 'Jo''hn', 'lastName'  : 'Doe','age': 23 }]}");
alert(employees.accounting[0].firstName);
```

I got the following  exception

> Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected '}'

help me?

Comment: I think the problem rely on 'Jo''hn' see the double ' that break the string ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... you have to use two backslashes to escape fully:

```
var jsonCallbackCode1 = eval("employees = { 'accounting' : [ { 'firstName' : 'Jo\\'\\'hn', 'lastName'  : 'Doe','age': 23 }]}");
            alert(employees.accounting[0].firstName);
```

Or of course you could just remove the apostrophes from the firstName altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
'Jo''hn'
```

is the problem.

Comment: yes ofcource the apostrophes is the problem. But i want to show the apostrophes  also, what should i do?

Comment: So doesn't Ambrosia's technique with the double backslash do the trick, either?

Answer (score 0):

The parser is choking on The 'Jo''hn' because of the single quote. Escape it with \'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var jsonCallbackCode1 = eval("employees = { 'accounting' : [ { 'firstName' : 'Jo\'\'hn', 'lastName'  : 'Doe','age': 23 }]}");
    alert(employees.accounting[0].firstName);
```